# Meaning of job recorded as "USAF – AFSC#29430"?

Tags: united-states, military-records, occupation

I am interested to know a description of the job recorded on old family papers as "USAF – AFSC#29430".

I cannot seem to find this job description anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

If I am not mistaken this speciality code used for Airman who were linguistic experts working for the A F Electronics Security Command.  The majority of whom I met, worked within top secret facilities. These individual usually attended Defense Language Institute.   The AFSC of the individual indicated he was in training.  Upon completion he would become a 5 Level Technician.  I am a  retired USAF MSGT 30399.

Answer (score 5):

According to this unofficial list of [US Air Force Job Speciality Codes](http://www.preservingourhistory.com/afsc.html) used during the 1960s and 1970s, no. 29430 corresponds to either:

> - Apprentice Electronic Emission Monitor/Analysis Specialist
> - Apprentice Electronic Intercept Operations/Analysis Specialist

Answer (score 1):

We had nothing to do with language.  Our jobs covered intercept of Soviet telemetry from ground based ICBM’s and. Missile launch.  We also intercepted Soviet satellite telemetry.  All information was taped at intercept an sent to NSA for analysis.  There weren’t a whole lot of us.  Oh, we were also task as early warning specialist during unexpected Soviet launch events.  In those events we only had seconds to alert NSA of the launch.

Answer (score 1):

29430 = Electronic intercept operations analysis.  I should know, I was one.  Our initial training at Keesler AFB was in radar intercept and analysis.  A sub field was telemetry which was taught for those selected from tech school at NSA at Ft Meade MD.  Either a 6 week or 12 weeks additional training prior to being sent to the field.  So our group was charged with intercepting soviet radar transmissions and the further analysis of the signals as well as soviet telemetry from missiles as well as satellites, weather, photo recon and manned missions.  With out a doubt the most interesting job I have ever had, and that was a long time ago, early to mid 60's.

Answer (score 0):

The job description included the, ". . . detection, interception, recording, analyzing, and reporting of non-communications, non-nuclear electromagnetic signals."  While at SAC, we concentrated on locating and verifying the location of Soviet Bloc radar systems.  When assigned to Berlin, our job was trying to detect, analyze, and defeat Soviet radar jamming in order to keep the air corridors open from West Germany to Berlin.  There were many different and specialized tasks depending on the assignment location.

Answer (score 0):

I was a 29450 stationed in Berlin. I was there from 1964 to 1967. When i first got there we just monitored the 3 air corridors from West Germany to Berlin. We installed the intercep monitoring site in 1965 or 1966 can't remember exactly. We were a small group of airmen.
Interesting is i can't find anything about my schooling at Keesler, they keep referring me to Morse Intercept.